# How get several horizontal barplots for many variables in same figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several categorical variables and I need to plot its horizontal barplots in function of the frequency of their modalities. for example, if I want to plot horizontal barplot of the variable `INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT` knowing that its modalities are:

```
> unique(DATABASE$INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT)
[1] Beaucoup    Un peu      Pas du tout
Levels: Beaucoup Pas du tout Un peu
```

then using the code above :

```
ords <- c("Beaucoup", "Un peu", "Pas du tout")

ggplot(DATABASE, aes(x = INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT)) + 
  geom_bar(fill = "orange", width = 0.7) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = ords) +
  coord_flip() + 
  xlab("Storm Type") + ylab("Number of Observations")
```

I get this [image]

Now I want to add all other categorical variables to get their horizontal bar plots in the same plot. 
For example, if I want to add also the `INTERET_COMPOSITION` variable which has the same modalities ("Beaucoup", "Un peu", "Pas du tout").

I try using this code

```
ggplot(DATABASE, aes(x = INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT)) + 
  geom_bar(fill = "orange", width = 0.7) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = ords) +
  coord_flip() + 
  xlab("Storm Type") + ylab("Number of Observations")+
  facet_wrap(~INTERET_COMPOSITION)
```

But, it doesn't give the needed results.

To make my example reproductible, this is a data set which contains 4 categorical variables having same modalities:

```
structure(list(INTERET_COMPOSITION = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Beaucoup", 
"Pas du tout", "Un peu"), class = "factor"), INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Beaucoup", "Pas du tout", "Un peu"), class = "factor"), 
    INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Beaucoup", 
    "Pas du tout", "Un peu"), class = "factor"), INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Beaucoup", "Pas du tout", "Un peu"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("INTERET_COMPOSITION", 
"INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT", "INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO", "INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 24L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 44L, 49L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 71L, 74L, 
75L, 80L, 81L, 84L, 86L, 90L, 92L, 95L, 96L, 99L, 100L, 103L, 
104L, 107L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Please, how should I do to plot their horizontal barplot in same figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to transform your data from wide to long

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  gather(k, v) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(v)) + 
  geom_bar(fill = "orange", width = 0.7) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  facet_wrap(~k)
```

[image]

Comment: Similar approach, but a different output if you want everything in one plot : `df %>%
  gather(k, v) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = v, fill=k)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 0.7, position="dodge") + 
  coord_flip()`

Comment: @AntoniosK, thank you! It's also a great idea!I really appreciate